# Why is m.module not causing my view to rerender in Mithril?

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

I thought that given an object with `controller` & `view` properties, when the controller's state changed (or an `m.prop` property was changed) it would rerender the template.  This isn't happening in my case (I have to use `redraw` directly).  What am I doing wrong here?
    ////////app.js

```
define([ 'mithril', 'propertyPane'],
  function(m, propertyPane){
    //div#properties exists
    m.module(document.getElementById('properties'),propertyPane);
});

///////propertyPane.js

define([ 'mithril', 'emitter'],
  function(m, emitter) {

    //mithril "namespace"
    var propertyPane = {};

    ///////////////////////
    //    Models         //
    ///////////////////////
    propertyPane.PropertyList = Array;

    propertyPane.Property = function(name, data) {
      //the following reflects the format of the data obects as sent by the event emitter
      this.name        = m.prop(name);
      this.value       = m.prop(data.value);
      this.type        = m.prop(data.valueType);
      this.visible     = m.prop(data.userVisible);
      this.editable    = m.prop(data.userEditable);
    };

    ///////////////////////
    //    Controller     //
    ///////////////////////
    propertyPane.controller = function() {

      this.properties = propertyPane.PropertyList();

      this.updatePropertyPane = function(sender) {
        //destroy current list
        this.properties.length = 0;

        for( var key in sender.currentItem.tag){
          this.properties.push(new propertyPane.Property(key, sender.currentItem.tag[key]));
        }
//>>>This is required to make the property pane to rerender:<<<
//      m.redraw(); //why?
//why doesn't redraw happen automatically (because I'm using m.module)??
      }.bind(this);

      //this reliably updates the the properties list
      //but rerender does not happen
      emitter.addCurrentItemChangedListener(this.updatePropertyPane);

    };

    ///////////////////////
    //    View           //
    ///////////////////////
    propertyPane.view = function(ctrl){
      return m('ul',
        ctrl.properties.map(function(property){
          return m('li', property.name() + ' ' + property.value());
        })
      );
    };

    return propertyPane;
});
```

I also tried adding a property called `foo` that updated in `updatePropertyPane` thus:

```
//in controller
this.foo = m.prop(Date.now());
//in updatePropertyPane
  this.foo(Date.now());
//in view
m('li', ...+this.foo()) //to make sure the view accesses this property.
```

That didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mithril automatically re-renders

- After all event handlers, e.g. m(tag, {onclick:...}, foo), which have fired are terminated.
- An AJAX request has terminated.
- Routing occurs.

Data binding value changes themselves do not cause re-renders and there are several reasons for this. To be fair, most data changes in Mithril occur within event handlers or during AJAX processing.

You can however force a re-render on a value change by using a modified version of m.prop():

```
mprop: function(store, onchange) {
    var prop = function() {
        if (arguments.length) {
            store = arguments[0];
            if (typeof onchange == 'function') { onchange(store); }
        }
        return store;
    }
    prop.toJSON = function() { return store; }
    return prop;
}

this.name = mprop("John", function(value) {
    // value is the new value
    // do a m.redraw() rather than m.startComputation / m.endComputation
});
```

However you do it, you should prefer m.redraw() for async events over m.startComputation / m.endComputation. It redraws the view for the currently active module and its called internally by Mithril's auto-redrawing system.

Answer (score 3):

Surprisingly, [`m.prop`](https://github.com/lhorie/mithril.js/blob/b486e53b4bb5dc6aeb8d6c9795279e7b32c9aa58/mithril.js#L460) returns a getter/setter very much without side effects.

Mithril [hooks](https://github.com/lhorie/mithril.js/blob/b486e53b4bb5dc6aeb8d6c9795279e7b32c9aa58/mithril.js#L197) itself in the event listeners of your view.

So in my very limited experience with Mithril, you should either use `m` to set your event listeners or use [`m.startComputation / m.endComputation`](https://lhorie.github.io/mithril/auto-redrawing) which call `m.redraw` with the added benefit of allowing different parts of your app to [only redraw once](https://github.com/lhorie/mithril.js/blob/b486e53b4bb5dc6aeb8d6c9795279e7b32c9aa58/mithril.js#L342) despite updating several things.